# Whether to use "le fait que" to express the idea of "the fact that"?

Tags: expressions

> {I said}: **Ton inquiétude** prouve bien que tu te laisses trop dominer par tes sentiments.
>
> {Not}: **Le fait que** tu t'en inquiètes prouve bien que tu te laisses trop dominer par tes sentiments.

I realise I don’t often start a sentence with "le fait que" in French in favour of more concise phrasing, whereas in stark contrast, I have no qualms about using a similar construction in English, German, Italian, or even in Japanese – "the fact that", "die Tatsache, dass" and "il solo fatto che" respectively.

How would French speakers usually express the idea of "the fact that" colloquially? For instance:

> **The fact that** you’re still worrying about it shows that your feelings are getting the better of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remaining of the sentence (*inquiètes prouve bien que tu te laisses trop dominer par tes sentiments*) is quite formal so it is difficult to start it with something casual.

Note that you can drop *le fait*:

> *Que tu t'en inquiètes prouve bien que tu te laisses trop dominer par tes sentiments.*

This is still formal though, actually more than with *le fait que* which can be used in casual French too.

Here is an attempt at a colloquial version:

> *Si tu t'inquiètes, c'est parce que tu es* (or *t'es*) *dépassé(e) par tes sentiments.*

and a stronger one (teenager slang attempt):

> *Si tu flippes, c'est qu'tu fais ta fillette, là !*

Comment: Hi. What do you think about replacing "que" with "parce que"? "Si tu t'inquiètes, c'est **parce que** t'es dépassé(e) par tes sentiments."

Comment: @Alone-zee Yes, that's better, pronounced *pasque t'es*. Thanks.

Comment: Pronounced _parce que_ works fine too. _pasque_ is 砕けた.

Comment: Je rangerais _pasque_ dans la catégorie _incorrect à l'écrit_, personnellement.

Comment: @Frank Il s'agit d'une retranscription « phonétique » d'une prononciation très courante mais ce n'est bien sûr pas du français écrit. c.f. TLFi *Prononc. et Orth.: [paʀs(ə)kə]. Fréq. chute de [ə] intérieur par anal. avec lorsque, puisque (d'apr. Fouché Prononc. 1959, p.98). Négligé [**paskə**].*

Comment: _Négligé!_: _esse_ pire que _marqué d'une F_? ;-)

Comment: @Frank Par Vaugelas ?  Peut-être vais-je trop loin dans mon interprétation de *colloquial*…

Comment: _Si tu flippes, c'est qu'tu fais ta fillette, là_: n'y-a-t'il pas un mot qu'on utilise maintenant, comme _faible_, ou _gentil_... Un mot a priori assez anodin, mais qui a acquis un sens plus fort récemment dans ce genre d'argot? _Fragile_?

Answer (score 1):

> **Le fait que** tu t'en inquiètes prouve bien que tu te laisses trop dominer par tes sentiments.

feels acceptable to me. I don't think there is anything wrong with having *le fait que* at the head of the sentence, and it doesn't sound too formal nor too familiar. There are of course alternatives, but there might not be any real need for these alternatives.